# .show function does not working in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, messagebox

I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 and when I write

```
MessageBox.show("hello ");
```

It says show does not exists in type of system.windows.form.Message-box.

Comment: Check if you are using Camel Case. Properties of classes starts with capital letter: `MessageBox.Show("Hello")`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is case sensetive language. So "Show" and "show" are different.
`MessageBox.Show("hello ");`
You may need to add using statement if there isn't System.Windows.Forms
`using System.Windows.Forms;`
You can also type fully.
`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("hello ");`
If dll is not referenced, it's in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: Don't reference it if you are not making a Winforms application! for example if you reference and use it in ASP.NET/MVC, it will not show but will be waiting for a response on the user account it is using on the server.

Comment: If you created a Winforms or WPF Project you have not to reference any library.